# Non-split Examples of Zappa-Szép Self-Extensions

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

What are some **interesting** examples of non-split Zappa-Szép self-extensions of a finite group?

More precisely, I am looking for finite groups $G$ with subgroups $H$ and $K$ such that:

1. We have $HK = G$ and $H\cap K=\{e\}$, (Zappa-Szép extension)
2. Neither $H$ nor $K$ is normal in $G$, (non-split extension)
3. The subgroups $H$ and $K$ are isomorphic as abstract group. (Self-extension)

Here is an *unsatisfactory* way to construct such examples: Take $G'$ to be an extension of $H'$ and $K'$ satisfying 1 and 2 above. Then, set $G:=G'\times G'$ with $H:=H'\times K'$ and $K:= K'\times H'$. This second extension will satisfy 1, 2, and 3.

Are there more interesting examples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did a quick computer search and found several examples of order $64$, so I suspect that there are lots of examples - probably too many for them all to be interesting.

I searched through transitive groups of degree $8$ and order $64$, looking for examples with a non-normal regular subgroup isomorphic to the point stabilizer.

I found three examples, ${\tt TransitiveGroup}(8,k)$ for $k=26,29$, and $31$. In the first two of these, the subgroups $H$ and $K$ in the product are dihedral, and in the third one they are elementary abelian.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "isomorphic to the point stabilizer"?

Comment: And do you mean SmallGroup(64,k)?

Comment: No, sorry, I meant${\tt TransitiveGroup}(8,k)$.

Comment: It would be interesting to know if there are any examples with $G$ simple or almost simple, I suspect there might be none.

Comment: @spin I wonder whether there are any (almost) simple groups with order a square? I have an idea that this has been investigated but I don't remember the details.

Comment: I think there is a classification of maximal subgroups of finite simple groups with order  $\geq \sqrt{|G|}$ (or something along these lines, cannot remember a reference right now), so checking if there are any examples might be doable.

Comment: @DerekHolt: There are some, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3252850/on-finite-simple-groups-whose-orders-are-perfect-powers), also question on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/336502/is-there-a-classification-of-finite-simple-groups-of-perfect-power-order) before